# 'System.Runtime, Version=4.2.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' could not be loaded

Tags: c#

I am working on an API .NET C# Server that is running .NET Framework 4.7.1 for an iOS/Android app. The software was created by an offshore team and it is my job to work and debug problems with it. Problem is every time I run this application through IIS Express in VS Community 2019, I get the following error in any browser. Where do I go from here to pinpoint the issue?

Tried installing all .NET Framework packs (targeting & sdk from 3.5 to 4.7.2), also Entity Framework 6 tools

Expected output through postman (For Example a request to log into my profile), 200 OK, actual output 500 Internal Server Error

[Error Message In Browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dsts0.png)

[Stack Trace For Error Message in Browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fBeJD.png)

Comment: Have you added any dependencies that might be built against .NET core 2.1 or 2.2?

Comment: I updated your tags since this has nothing to do with `sql`.  Are you sure you have the `nuget` package installed?

Comment: It seems like you're running the project with a different set of `frameworks` (pun intended). Are you sure it's .NET Framework, not .NET Core?

Comment: One of the offshore people mentioned they added dependencies for .NET core. Not sure where though. Kind of a big solution with a lot of projects

Comment: Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core is installed through NuGet Package Manager, as well as EntityFrameWork

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that all your projects reference the same System.Runtime with Version=4.2.1.0 and that is added trough Nuget package manager. If is added trough 'Add reference' -> 'Assemblies' remove it, go to Nuget package manager and add/update System.Runtime in correct version in relevant projects.

Comment: Isn't it part of the framework? There's no 4.2.1.0 on NuGet: https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Runtime/

Comment: OMG you are right. It has been removed. Then you have to go with the latest version probably (4.3.1). You will have to update it in all places.